# Relative import of submodule

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.x

In Python, how do I perform the equivalent of the following

```
import http.client
```

but using a relative import:

```
from . import http.client
import .http.client
```

For a package `http` in the current package? I want to then access the `client` module through it's parent name, `http.client`, as I would be able if I did the top level import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is this:

```
from ..http import client
```

Answer (score 3):

I would look for inspiration at the corresponding [PEP 0328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision). If you are in http.__init__.py, and want to access client:

```
from . import client
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import it with 
    from . import http

However, at that point you will not have loaded the http.client module, and you can't access it:

```
>>> http.client
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

There are various ways of getting around this. The simplest one is to do this in `http/__init__.py`

```
from . import client
```

Another things you can do are

```
import types
http = types.ModuleType('http')

from .http import client
http.client = client
```

Which you can do if it is unpractical to modify the `http/__init__.py`

However, since I assume this is to provide a drop-in replacement of http.client for some reason, I'd recommend you to do this:

```
try:
    from .http import client
except ImportError:
    from http import client
```

And then use the name client consistently instead. That's definitely the easiest, and prettiest solution

Or, if you don't want to use client as a name:

```
try:
    from .http import client as http_client
except ImportError:
    from http import client as http_client
```