# In my flask application I get this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

Tags: python

In my flask application I get this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'` when I run `flask shell` in cmd. What could be the possible reason behind it?
Below is my Project Structure:

```
app/
    email.py
    models.py
    __init__.py
    main/
        errors.py
        forms.py
        views.py
        __init__.py
    static/
        favicon.ico
        styles.css
    templates/
        404.html
        500.html
        base.html
        index.html
        mail/
            new_user.html
            new_user.txt
    __pycache__/
        __init__.cpython-310.pyc
migrations/
    alembic.ini
    env.py
    README
    script.py.mako
    versions/
    __pycache__/
        env.cpython-310.pyc
tests/
    test.py
    __init__.py
venv/
```

This is inside `app/main/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from . import views, errors

main_blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__)
```

The import statement in `app/__init__.py`:

```
from main import main_blueprint
```

I tried searching in Google but in vain.

Comment: You might need to say `from app.main import main_blueprint`. Is your app already installed into your venv locally with `pip install -e .`?

Comment: Or use a relative import: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893209/relative-import-of-submodule

Comment: Okay after an extensive search I found that I have to import views and errrors after defining main_blueprint `from flask import Blueprint
main_blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__)
from . import views, errors`  This solves my issue.

Comment: Dang, I should have thought about that! Our code style checker (flake8, maybe pylint too) kept complaining about that import at the end, and we had to add `# noqa: E402 F401` to silence it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I am posting my comment as an answer.
After an extensive search I found that I have to **import views and errrors after defining main_blueprint**.

```
from flask import Blueprint 
main_blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__) 
from . import views, errors
```

This solves my issue.